# How to Merge Project Module Into New Git Branch

Tags: android, git, android-studio, merge, branch

I'm fairly new to git and I have an Android Studio project containing multiple modules. Assume I have two branches, Dev and Main, where Main contains a subset of the Dev branch's modules and changes. I want to create a new branch based off of Main, but updating its module A (which may or may not exist yet in Main) with all the code from module A in Dev. Sort of like copy-pasting that module over whatever may be in Main's module. I understand there's this thing called "cherry picking" where you can do that for a commit, but this module is spread across many commits. Is there a way just to copy the module over in its entirety?

Answer (score 1):

```
  well if understood your problem correctly please try the below solution
```

> 1. create a branch out of DEV like  DEV_MAIN_UPDATED_MODULE_A.
> 2. download the DEV_MAIN_UPDATED_MODULE_A studio.
> 3. delete other modules not required ones.
> 4. take a pull from MAIN.
> 5. resolve the conflicts if any.
> 6. commit and push the changes to DEV_MAIN_UPDATED_MODULE_A.
>
> by this your safe and clean. any time you go back your previous latest
>   state.